# DataGridViewComboBoxColumn DataSource?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview, datatable

I'm trying to get something set up in a `DataGridView`. It seems like this should be pretty straightforward but I'm having trouble. I want to display three columns:

- CodeID
- CodeName
- ComboBox with DisplayMember of TypeName, ValueMember of TypeID

I want to be able to select from all possible values of `TypeName`. Here's my dilemma:

If I load all of this into one `DataTable` and set the `DataGridView` as the `DataSource`, I can display the existing `TypeName` for that record, but the combo box will not include any other values. If I set the `DataSource` for the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` to a separate `DataTable` that includes all possible `TypeNames`, the existing value is not displayed.

`DataGridView` is really annoying to work with so either a solution for this or a viable alternative would be appreciated.

Edit: it appears the issue is caused by my wanting to have a separate item for `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember`. The following works, if I don't worry about setting the `ID` as the `ValueMember`:

```
var typeColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
    DataSource = typeList,
    DisplayMember = "Type",
    ValueMember = "Type",
    DataPropertyName = "Type"
}
```

If I do the following, the right types are selected, but I can't change the selection in the combo box:

```
var typeColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
    DataSource = typeList,
    DisplayMember = "Type",
    ValueMember = "TypeID",
    DataPropertyName = "TypeID"
}
```

If I use the following I get a `FormatException` error as it's trying to populate:

```
var typeColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
{
    DataSource = typeList,
    DisplayMember = "Type",
    ValueMember = "TypeID",
    DataPropertyName = "Type"
}
```

**edit**: `typeList` is a simple `DataTable` populated by the following:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT IT.InsuranceTypeID, IT.[Type]
FROM InsuranceType IT
WHERE IT.ClientID = @ClientID
ORDER BY [Type]
```

Comment: Are you setting the DataPropertyName on the DGVCBC? Also, epic profile icon.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/952b1cc9-4ba7-4b16-abdf-be2cdfde6460/

Comment: Can you post how you setup `typeList` and the structure you are adding to the list?  The types of `DataPropertyName` and `ValueMember` must be the same, which is probably why you are getting the exception in the last example.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, I came up with an example `ClientInfo` and `InsuranceDetails` that I think might mimic what you are trying to do.  Let me know if these details arent quite right.  This example will populate the `DataGridViewComboBox` and set the value based on the `InsuranceDetails` (specifically at: `InsurDetailz = all_insurance_types[2]`)

```
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      private ClientInfo _myClient;
      private BindingList<InsuranceDetails> all_insurance_types =
         new BindingList<InsuranceDetails>();

      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();

         DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
         grid.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
         grid.AutoGenerateColumns = true;

         all_insurance_types.Add(new InsuranceDetails(1, "Health"));
         all_insurance_types.Add(new InsuranceDetails(2, "Home"));
         all_insurance_types.Add(new InsuranceDetails(3, "Life"));

         var col = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
         {
            DataSource = all_insurance_types,
            HeaderText = "Insurance Type",
            DataPropertyName = "InsurDetailz",
            DisplayMember = "ItType",
            ValueMember = "Self",
         };

         _myClient = new ClientInfo { 
            InsurDetailz = all_insurance_types[2], Name = "Jimbo" };
         grid.Columns.Add(col);
         grid.DataSource = new BindingList<ClientInfo> { _myClient };
         this.Controls.Add(grid);

         this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Form1_FormClosing);
      }

      void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
      {
         // make sure its updated
         InsuranceDetails c = _myClient.InsurDetailz;
         string name = _myClient.Name;
         // Place breakpoint here to see the changes in _myClient 
         throw new NotImplementedException();
      }
   }

   class ClientInfo
   {
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public InsuranceDetails InsurDetailz { get; set; }
   }

   class InsuranceDetails
   {
      public int InsuranceTypeID { get; set; }
      public String ItType { get; set; }
      public InsuranceDetails Self { get { return this; } }

      public InsuranceDetails(int typeId, String itType)
      {
         this.InsuranceTypeID = typeId;
         this.ItType = itType;
      }
   }
```

Comment: The secret is the `Self` property.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar (I think) issue, and the solution for me was to set the `DataSource` for the `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` **before** setting the `DataSource` for the `DataGridView`.

In my case, my DataSources are a `List<T>` and a `BindingList<T>` respectively but it should work the same with DataTables:

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn categoryColumn = (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)_ItemsGrid.Columns["CategoryID"];
categoryColumn.DataSource = categories;

_ItemsGrid.DataSource = items;
```

Comment: Unfortunately this did not help.

Comment: This helped me alot when using Eloquera and binding some complex class to a datagrid. Thanks!

Comment: This answer was magic for me, finding it 10 years later.